# Disable modal dialog in view with group by

Tags: list-view, modal-dialog

I'm creating a solution using SharePoint 2010 that contains a list (`list1`) with a lookup column (`list2_column`) to another list (`list2`). The main view for `list1` is grouped by `list2_column`. Both lists were created with `NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE"`.

So my list view might look like this:

```
+ list2_column: some_item (3)
    [ ] list1_item1
    [ ] list1_item2
    [ ] list1_item3
```

The problem I'm having is that when the user clicks on `some_item`, SharePoint opens up the display form for the item in a modal dialog. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

P.S. If it makes any difference, everything in my solution is created during the FeatureActivated event.

EDIT: Turns out what I was trying to do is possible by building on Ksesh's answer a little:

```
<a href="{substring-before(substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name], 'href=&quot;'), '&quot;')}">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name], '&gt;'), '&lt;')" />
</a>
```

This makes a link without the onclick event that opens the modal dialog. But seeing as how I have quite a few list views showing mostly lookup columns, all opening in dialogs, I think it's going to be easier to do what I want in jQuery. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('table.ms-listviewtable a[onclick]').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do followwing. In spd open your view, go to the lookup value `<xsl:value-of>` tag
`$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]` and change it to

```
substring-before(substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],'>'),'<')
```

This will disable model dialog for this lookup column totally in this list view.

[more detail](http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/04/remove-hyperlink-for-lookup-columns-in.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I needed. Now I just have to figure out how to remove the `onclick` from the link instead of the whole tag, and how to automate the process during deployment instead of using spd.